# Is there a Button class in VS Studio 2019 preview C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a program in C# and see no button form on in the controls area [controls in VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kscNx.png)

Comment: can you search in toolbox with name button

Comment: thanks for responding Keshav.  I tried that, the only thing that comes up is radio button.

Comment: If you are referring to a Winforms button, you need to be using.net core 3. “ This article describes what is new in .NET Core 3.0. One of the biggest enhancements is support for Windows desktop applications (Windows only).” (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0)

Comment: The `Button` class has been supported since Preview 1.  See screenshot and "Controls included in Preview 1:" list at [Introducing .NET Core Windows Forms Designer Preview 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean your Visual Studio(Open the Cmd window > to the “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE” where installed VS > Input the command(devenv /resetuserdata) > restart the Visual Studio)

you can also try

You can add the missing controls by below steps.

a. Right click the blank of any Tab, then choose the “Choose items…”.

b. Choose one tab on the “Choose Toolbox items” dialog.

c. Chose the controls that you want to add.

Comment: Brilliant!!  It worked.  Thanks for your help. Stay healthy, stay safe, keep coding.